# Prevent Javascript Injection in data attribute

Tags: javascript, php, xss, code-injection

I have a script that pulls a text from an API and sets that as a tooltip in my html.

```
<div class="item ttip" data-html="<?php echo $obj->titleTag;?>">...</div>
```

The API allows html and javascript to be entered on their side for that field.

I tried this `$obj->titleTag = htmlentities(strip_tags_content($this->channel->status)));`

I now had a user that entered the following (or similar, he is blocked now I cannot check it again):

```
\" <img src="xx" onerror=window.location.replace(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAISUDbjXj0)>
```

which does not get caught by the above.
I could `str_replace` the window.location stuff, but that seems dirty.
What would be the right approach? I am reading a lot of "Whitelists" but I don't understand the concept for such a case.

//EDIT strip_tags_content comes from here: https://php.net/strip_tags#86964

Answer (score 1):

Well, It's not tags you're replacing now but code within tags. You need to allow certain attributes in your code rather than stripping tags since you've only got one tag in there ;)

What you wanna do is check for any handlers being bound in the JS, a [full list here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp), and then remove them if anything contains something like `onerror` or so